# React-Native Responsive Background Images with Static Resources?

Tags: reactjs, background-image, react-native, static-resource

I can't figure this out, even though it seems a very common use case.

I want a full screen background image in all pages of my app.

- This should be from a static resource.
- And it should be the best quality for each device display size, iPhone 4 / 5 / 6 / ...
- Also a nice to have would be a landscape alternative when the user changes the orientation of the device.

What is the right way of doing this?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try this library:

https://github.com/huiseoul/react-native-fit-image

```
<FitImage
  source={{ uri: 'http://facebook.github.io/react/img/logo_og.png' }}
  style={styles.fitImage}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not hard. React-native have [official support for static image](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html#static-resources) and [3rd part viewport plugin](https://github.com/pjjanak/react-native-viewport) to handle device screen size and orientation change event, all you need is mix them in a component.

Comment: Thank you. I came across these already, but it doesn't really explain how require(image!...) the correct image for the current device and orientation in the right resolution from the XCAssets. Could you give an example here please?